# Adding labels to candlestick series

Tags: python, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

The following code snippet is plotting two candlestick series of 4 bars:

```
from pylab import * 
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

quotes = [(734542.0, 1.326, 1.3287, 1.3322, 1.3215), (734543.0, 1.3286, 1.3198, 1.3292, 1.3155), (734546.0, 1.321, 1.3187, 1.3284, 1.3186), (734547.0, 1.3186, 1.3133, 1.3217, 1.308)]
quotes2 = [(734542.0, 1.0, 0.9979, 1.0046, 0.9953), (734543.0, 0.998, 0.9991, 1.0024, 0.9952), (734546.0, 0.9991, 1.0014, 1.0038, 0.9951), (734547.0, 1.003, 1.0028, 1.0047, 1.0002)]

fig, ax = subplots()
candlestick(ax,quotes,width = 0.5, colorup = "green", colordown = "red")
candlestick(ax,quotes2, width = 0.2, colorup = "grey", colordown = "black")
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
ax.legend(loc=3)


plt.show()
```

I'm not being able to add a label to the two series and on the web I didn't find anything yet. What's the right syntaxis to do this?

```
candlestick(ax,quotes,width = 0.5, label = "Series 1") #but it doesn't work
```

**NOTE**: what I need is not annotating something on a specific point such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454588/adding-labels-to-candlestick-chart-in-matplotlib) or other threads explain, but a proper label to be added to the chart legend since the final purpose is to plot several normalized price series to be visually compared each other.

**ADD**: more precisely, the "but it doesn't work" rough attempt doesn't work indeed for the following expected error:

```
TypeError: candlestick() got an unexpected keyword argument 'label'
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is supported (see [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/legend_guide.html#legend-of-complex-plots)). The best you may be able to do is create a `Text` object for each of the candlestick plots.

Comment: @Ffisegydd it's true, it seems they have not thought about a legend for candlestick charts yet... but see the solution below, it's not 100% a proper candlestick legend but it seems a very good solution though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need changes to a few place to get the labels:

```
C1=candlestick(ax,quotes,width = 0.5, colorup = "green", colordown = "red")
C2=candlestick(ax,quotes2, width = 0.2, colorup = "grey", colordown = "black")
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.autoscale_view()
ax.legend((C1[1][0],C2[1][0]), ('label1', 'label2'),loc=3)
```

[image]

The problem is that we have `colorup` and `colordown` here, you can't easily put them both in the legend (well, you may be able to, that will be quite complex).

So why `C2[1][0]`? Because this is what `C1` is:

```
In [5]:

C1
Out[5]:
([<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x76b3c90>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x759d3b0>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x759dab0>,
  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x75a61d0>],
 [<matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x76b3df0>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x759d590>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x759dc90>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x75a63b0>])
```

If you have other plot that will follow the candlestick plots:

```
plt.hlines(1.10, plt.xlim()[0], plt.xlim()[1], label='Other Plot') #such as an horizontal line
#And may be other plots.
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
import operator
hl = sorted(zip(handles, labels),
            key=operator.itemgetter(1)) #sort is optional
handles2, labels2 = zip(*hl)
handles2=list(handles2)+[C1[1][0],C2[1][0]] #put the candel plot legend to the end
labels2=list(labels2)+['label1', 'label2'] #put the candel plot legend to the end
ax.legend(handles2, labels2, loc=8)
```

[image]

Taking from the [documents](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/legend_guide.html).

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Great! The question is definitely answered, I take chance to ask you a detail that I will need: this charting system, apart for plotting the candlestick series, will also plot other curves (such as indicators) and the legend of it is created at later stage, so is overriding the original one. How would you suggest to proceed to join all the legends? Since I'm labelling the Rectangle objects, I was expecting the legends to be joint?

Comment: I guess you will be making the legends in the very end, see edit.